# For a 100% table, how to spread elements horizontally evenly inside <td>?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

For example, I have a table which the first column has some elements with different length:

```html
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
  <tr><td><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>a</span><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span><td>1</td></tr>  
<table>
```

How to add space to elements so that the elements in <td> is evenly distributed?

I tried:

```css
span{
  display:inline-block;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container.space-around {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.spaceBetween{
  display:space-between;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
  <tr class="container space-around"><td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="container space-around"><td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="container space-around"><td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="container space-around"><td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span></td><td>1</td></tr>  
</table>
```

but not working.

Comment: He wants the widths of each column to be the same as that of the biggest column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.spaceBetween {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="text-align:center;width:100%">
  <tr class="container space-around">
    <td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container space-around">
    <td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container space-around">
    <td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="container space-around">
    <td class="spaceBetween"><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span><span>a</span></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You just didn't place your flex in the right place and were completely breaking the table. I've changed it so the flex is applied to the cell.

Answer (score -1):

To evenly distribute the elements in the first column of a table, you can use CSS to apply a "text-align: justify" property to the cells in that column. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
html
<style>
  .distribute {
    text-align: justify;
  }
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="distribute">Element 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="distribute">Element 2</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="distribute">Element 3</td>
    <td>Value 3</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- Add more rows as needed -->
</table>
```

By applying the "distribute" class to the cells in the first column (in this case, the elements), the "text-align: justify" property will evenly distribute the content in each cell. In this way, the elements will be spaced to fill the entire width of the column. Don't forget to adjust the structure and content of the table to suit your specific needs.

Comment: reponses en langues different que anglais sont non-acceptable. s'il-vous-plait reformule votre reponse en anglais.

Comment: In which language is this written?

Comment: in English, but it's very bad